# Mass Point Geometry Question

Tags: geometry

In the triangle $ABC$, let $E$ be a point on $BC$ such that $BE : EC =
3: 2$. Pick points $D$ and $F$ on the sides $AB$ and $AC$ , correspondingly, so that
$3AD = 2AF$ . Let $G$ be the point of intersection of $AE$ and $DF$ . Given that $AB = 7$
and $AC = 9$, find the ratio $DG: GF$.

I have been working on trying to solve this problem.  I am having difficulty relating the length of $AB =7$  and the ratios given to find $AD:BD$.  Similarly I am having trouble finding ratio of $FC:AF$.  I am sure that I can solve this problem if someone can give me a hint on how to find those ratios.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weights at C=3 and B=2.  Let AF=3y, AD=2y then FC=9-3y and DB=7-2y.  Let the weight at A =x then we get 3(9-3y)=x(3y) and x(2y)=2(7-2y) so y=2.  AD=4, DB=3, AF=6, and FC=3.  Thus weight at A must be 3/2.  At balance point F we get weight of 9/2 and at balance point D we get 7/2.  So DG/GF= 9/2 / 7/2 = 9:7.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $D'\in AB$ be such that $CD'\parallel FD$ and let $G'=AE\cap CD'$.
By similarity, $\frac{DG}{GF}=\frac{DG'}{G'C}$. Let $H=BG'\cap AC$. By [Ceva's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem) 
$$ 1=\frac{BE}{EC}\cdot \frac{CH}{HA}\cdot \frac{AD'}{D'B} = \frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{CH}{HA}\cdot\frac{\frac{2}{3}b}{c-\frac{2}{3}b} $$
hence $\frac{CH}{HA}=\frac{c-\frac{2}{3}b}{b}$. By [Van Obel's theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/VanObel.shtml)
$$ \frac{CG'}{G'D}=\frac{CE}{EB}+\frac{CH}{HA} = \frac{2}{3}+\frac{c}{b}-\frac{2}{3}=\frac{c}{b} $$
hence if $c=AB=7$ and $b=AC=9$ it follows that $\frac{DG}{GF}=\color{red}{\large \frac{9}{7}}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need a method for finding the ratios needed from above using mass point geometry techniques.

Comment: @jim: "mass point geometry" and barycentric coordinates are the same thing. What are your attempts?

Comment: I have assigned weights to the vertices C and B of 3 and 2.  Then I have been trying to find the weight at vertex A.  I need the ratio of AD:DB and AF:FC.  I know you have to use the lengths given and the fact that AD:AF is 2:3.  I have tried systems of equations in may ways to solve for those ratios and have not found a solution. I need to solve this by showing the weights and how I got them.  I've tried many things and am not getting your answer.

Comment: This is nothing more than a line-line-intersection problem in a skew reference system. Please study Ceva's and Val Obel's theorems and solve it as you like it.